# Create Employee Directory with data from a list

Tags: directory

Disclaimer: totally new to sharepoint, SP 2016

Hi , my company just used sharepoint as our intranet portal and currently the employee directory design are a page with excel file which was converted to a webpage.

My question is how can i create an employee directory with a list that has all the employee data because AD is not well maintained and the information is not updated except employee email and position.

In the list i have already created has >5k items which consist of name, extension number, department, mobile number and etc. Any good solution on how can i get the data from the list and display it on a page with search function and refinements?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If there is a chance that the list is about to grow and if you are hesitant in moving beyond the >5k limit, then for better long term list management, i suggest creating multiple list for holding the employee data, based on their alphabetical name.

- EmployeeDirectory_A-I (employee first name starting with A to I)
- EmployeeDirectory_J-R (employee first name starting with J to R)
- EmployeeDirectory_S-Z (employee first name starting with S to Z)

Now coming to your search, you can then use the below means -

1. SharePoint Search using Result Scope ([article](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/sagarp/search-scopes-in-sharepoint-2013-using-result-sources/))
2. Use CSOM scripts and HTML for a customised search.

Comment: Please mark this as answer, if it solves your issue :)